# How to make the mail cache when I use mailcore2?Are there some good ways?（IOS）

Tags: ios, iphone, mailcore2

I want to make the mail cache for my IOS app.But the mailcore2 dosen't provide the method.Please give me some ideas.I have no idea......

Comment: Current goal of mailcore2 is not to provide any mail storage / caching.